# Не очень плавная работа javascript

Tags: javascript

Столкнулся с проблемой. От чего зависит плавность работы javascript и сам fps в браузерах? Посоветуйте темы для изучения данного вопроса. Есть блок, который приклеен к TOP посредством javascript, а не position:fixed и при скроллинге на некоторых браузерах работает плавно, как и position:fixed, а на некоторых замечаются скачки.

Comment: Думаю это зависит от движка js в браузере и количеству прилетаемых ивентах

Answer (score 1):

JS и CSS должны работать в связке друг с другом. В идеале JS код должен только манипулировать CSS классами, благодаря чему будет достигнуто чётное разграничение логики и представления.